# NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow for pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android

When I launch my app on pre-Lollipop devices I get this error and the app crashes (on Lollipop the app works fine):

```
NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow
```

In my layout I use:

`DrawerLayout` (`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`)

`Toolbar` (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`)

`ViewPager` (`android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`)

`PagerTabStrip` (`android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip`)

`FloatingActionButton` (`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`).

In the build.gradle (Module: app) file I have:
dependencies {

```
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile ('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1')
```

...

In the Project window I can see the following external libraries:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7p0FSMdyvwAdGwyNmVha2M0SWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Change the support v4 compile to use 22.2.0 to match the others.

Comment: I changed it to 22.2.0 but now I have this error (for all Android versions): Error:(12, 1) error: cannot access DialogStyle
class file for android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment$DialogStyle not found

Comment: Ok, I changed the support v4 to version 22.2.1 and now everything works fine.